# How to do javascript for this if-else statement and connect them into database?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, if-statement

```
namespace WebApplication27
{
public partial class TestingDB : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string A;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DD1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            A = "A";
        }
        else if (DD1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            A = "B";
        }
        else if (DD1.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            A = "C";
        }
        else
        {
            A = "D";
        }



        String query = "Insert INTO Test (SelectValue,DsiplayValue)values('" + A + "','" + TextB1.Text + "')";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelloWorldConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

}

Im doing a interface where it have a dropdown list and a text box. I have already connect dropdownlist and the textbox to pass it's value. Dropdownlist (id=DD1) and a textbox (id=TextB1). This is my code where it connects to database. Can I do javascript instead of doing if else statement ?

Comment: You might have a typo in Insert statement: `DsiplayValue`

Comment: In `TextB1.Text` enter `'); DROP TABLE Test ; -- ` and run your code with it. Be sure to back up your database first.

Comment: @John A nicer way of saying it is that this code has SQL injection issues. Also, not disposing connection and command in `using` blocks

Comment: @Charlieface It may be nicer, but I'm pretty sure that a practical demonstration is more convincing of the need to fix it than someone saying "Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection", especially if the developer has no idea what SQL injection is. I did tell them to back up their database first. :)

Comment: I suppose I'm just a soft heart [#LittleBobbyTables](https://xkcd.com/327/) :-)